# No response from journal after submission

Tags: journals, paper-submission, retraction

I submitted a paper to a journal just before Christmas time last year. The journal didn't send any note whether they have received the paper or not. Mid of January this year, I sent again an email asking whether they have received my submission or not, but still, didn't receive any reply.
Just last week, I sent an email to the main publisher regarding the matter, and they told me they just emailed the main editor, who will contact me soon. But until now, I have yet to receive any reply from the editor.

I am thinking of emailing to let the editor know that I will wait for another week before I will retract my submission to be sent to other journal. I understand editors are busy people, but I think they should notify the author that they have received their submission. What do you think?

Also, from SJR Scimago, this journal is from the UK. Nothing against people from UK, just want to ask whether it is vacation season now for the academics, which in that case I should wait a little longer?

Thanks!

Comment: How does the submission process work for this journal? Is it via a web portal? If yes, did you try logging in again and check for status of your manuscript there?

Comment: No. Paper is submitted through email only..

Comment: That doesn't sound so good, which publisher is this? Have you consulted with colleagues about the reputation of that journal.

Comment: It is from Taylor and Francis. It is ISI indexed so I suppose it is reputable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's February, so the holiday season is long over, and no reasonable journal ought to have lost its entire staff to vacation for so long.  Moreover, most journals have an automated system that will acknowledge your paper and tell you about its current status.  If this journal hasn't got the infrastructure to even acknowledge your submission in over a month, then I would it a rather dubious prospect for publication.

Note, however, that there is another possibility that you should rule out before withdrawing, and that is whether either your emails to the journal or their emails to you are getting lost in a spam filter.  This is particularly likely if you are from the developing world, to which blacklists are often applied quite carelessly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I sent the email through my university email in Japan. In that case, I guess I will retract my paper

Comment: I'd give them one more (brief) chance myself, but I'm a bit of a soft touch perhaps.